# Run X11 only apps with custom font size and font style

Tags: x11, fonts, fontconfig

How to run a X11 only app with user defined font size and font style ?

Is it possible to run different X11 apps with different font size and style ?
e.g. Run `xclipboard` with font **FreeSans** 14px and run `xman` with **Roboto** 12px .

Is there any environment variable available to override font settings of GUI apps ? like

`env FONT_SIZE="16px" xterm`

Answer (score 3):

### Classic X11 applications

For classic X11 applications (such as xclipboard, xman, xterm, etc.), yes, there is a way, through **[X resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources)**. X resources settings are conventionally stored in a file called `~/.Xresources` which is loaded by the command `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` during the startup of your session (not all environments load it by default though).

You can find examples of X resource settings in the `app-defaults` directory (the exact location can vary: `/usr/share/X11/app-defaults`, `/usr/X11/lib/app-defaults`, `/etc/X11/app-defaults`, …). These are the system-wide settings for each application. You can also run [`appres`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/appres.1.html) to list the user-defined settings loaded in the server plus the system-wide settings in `app-defaults`, e.g. `appres Xman`. Note that `app-defaults` files and `appres` output omits the class name, but in your own configuration file, you should start every setting with a class or instance name, otherwise the setting will apply to every application.

A resource setting consists of a qualified widget component name and a value, e.g. `XClipboard.form.text.textSink.font: fixed`. See [.Xresources settings in effect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8818/xresources-settings-in-effect/8847#8847) and [the manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html#sect13) for more information on resource identifiers. Note that X resources are case sensitive. Conventionally, class names start with an uppercase letter, and instance names start with a lowercase letter. You can use the wildcard `*` to stand for any number of components, e.g. `XClipboard*font` would set all fonts in XClipboard.

Note that classic X11 applications use server-side text rendering. They do not have the same fonts available as applications that use client-side rendering with fonts managed by fontconfig. You can use `xfontsel` to see what fonts are available server-side. X11 fonts use a 14-part naming scheme encoding the font, size, boldness, etc.; see [the manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html#sect8) for detail.

Most classic X11 applications support resource settings on the command line, with arguments like `-xrm '*text*font: fixed'`, as well as some shortcuts such as `-font fixed` to set the main font. Xterm supports those, and in addition supports client-side rendering, which can be set through resources or through the command line argument `-fa` (see the manual for details).

### GTK applications

The GTK font is normally set by the theme and can be overridden in `~.gtkrc`.

```
gtk-font-name = "Roboto 12"
```

You can run an application with an alternate gtkrc file or alternate theme through environment variables. With the older Gtk2:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/path/to/alternate/gtkrc my-gtk2-app
```

The newer Gtk3 is expectedly less configurable, but you can use an alternate theme:

```
GTK_THEME=/path/to/alternate/theme.css my-gtk3-app
```

You can also look for application-specific settings with [gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) (GTK 2) or dconf-editor (GTK 3) [or gsettings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database). I don't think it's common for GTK applications to have specific font settings though.